# How to add stored procedure in to windows Installer

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a simple stored procedure like below

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertMessage]  
    --@msgTypeName NVARCHAR(50), 
    --@msgTypeDescription NVARCHAR   
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblMessageLookup]
    (strMessageType, strMessageDescription,DateCreated,DateModified)
    VALUES
    ('TrainList', 'TrainList',GETDATE(),GETDATE());
       INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblMessageLookup]
    (strMessageType, strMessageDescription,DateCreated,DateModified)
    VALUES
    ('Schedule', 'Schedule',GETDATE(),GETDATE());
     INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblMessageLookup]
    (strMessageType, strMessageDescription,DateCreated,DateModified)
    VALUES
    ('Stockpile', 'Stockpile',GETDATE(),GETDATE());
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblMessageLookup]
    (strMessageType, strMessageDescription,DateCreated,DateModified)
    VALUES
    ('Forecast', 'Forecast',GETDATE(),GETDATE());
END
```

If I execute the store procedure it will create three rows in my table but I am trying to do this process automatically. So I was thinking to create a windows installer for this, because rest of the project (Windows application) have a windows installer to install the project.

Is there any way I can create installer for the stored procedure or add it to the existing windows installer ?

Comment: does the installer currently create the database?  Whatever mechanism creates the database should also own creating the procedure

Comment: thanks bryanmac,no the windows installer won't create the database,i have installer to create a desktop icon for my windows appliaction,i want to add this is a part of installation.

Comment: OK - what creates the database then.  Is it pre-created by a DBA or is there another tool/script/process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN has an article on how to use custom actions in installation projects in order to create databses during installation.

[Walkthrough: Using a Custom Action to Create a Database During Installation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/49b92ztk%28vs.71%29.aspx)

You could change the SQL they use to create the database, with your own code - to either create the procedure, execute it or both (it's not clear from your question which you are wanting to do).